# ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer una captura de pantalla usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de hacer un `screenshot` usando `javascript`, he encontrado como hacer un `screenshot` de una `url` pero lo que necesito es hacer la captura de la pantalla que está viendo el usuario.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a la vista del navegador?¿O a una captura de pantalla en sí (otros programas, etc.)?

Comment: al código le falta información? porque no me funciona. Yo le agregué en el head la línea para obtener los datos del archivo html2canvas y otros cambios pero no logré que funcione

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hacer screenshot es un comportamiento nativo del sistema operativo, por lo tanto, desde tu navegador no puedes acceder a éste. Lo que puedes hacer es transformar el documento HTML a canvas y posteriormente a una URL por medio de la función `toDataURL()`.

El siguiente ejemplo hace uso de la librería [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

```js
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered (canvas) {
    var link = document.getElementById('download');;
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.href = image;
    link.download = 'screenshot.png';
  }
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hola, éste es un test para tomar una screenshot y descargarla.
  <br/><br/>
  <a id="download">Tomar screenshot y descargar</a>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Si quieres que se descargue automáticamente solo llama a la función `click` sobre el link (`link.click()`).

Comment: Ok, esa me parece una buena opcion, y hay alguna manera de hacer una captura de pantalla usando node.js?

Comment: Claro. Con Node.js puedes acceder a algunas APIs del SO anfitrión. Para Windows lo mejor será combinar JavaScript con C# mediante Edge.js.